# Issue with the Network Link Conditioner on iOS devices (iPad): the list with condition is blank

Tags: ipad, developer-mode

I faced with followijg issue on iPad device with Network Link Conditioner:
there is no any option for selecting after openning the Network Link Conditioner, previously I was able to select LTE/3G and etc., but for now it`s not working, and I could not add any options manually.

Device model: iPad air 3 generation
iOS version: 16.4.1

Did somebody faced with the same issue, and maybe you have any workaround?

Thank you!

Try to reload device,
Clear the network setting on the device and reset them to default.